# Reading TAG from Rockwell PLC using Java - for Android app

Tags: android, plc

Please could you let me know how to read specific TAGs from the Rockwell PLC and display on Android device.  Is there any API available to connect and fetch the data ?
I know the IP address of the machine where the PLC is installed and also it is WiFi enabled and has Ethernet connectivity.

I see a solution provided in Python in a different thread , but what i am looking for is more Java based solution.

Thanks

Comment: This is the related question referenced by the OP: [Simple APP to read and write data to ROCKWELL PLC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25294373/2600278)

Answer (score 0):

It's a very new implementation, but libplctag does have an Android wrapper now: https://github.com/libplctag/libplctag4android

I haven't used it, but I am one of the maintainers of the libplctag.NET wrapper and the base c library (libplctag) is quite mature and the documentation is good. It definitely works with AB PLCs.